# OpenCV.JS Uncaught ReferenceError: cv is not defined

Tags: javascript, opencv3.0

I am working on a computer vision project using OpneCV.JS and springboot using Thymeleaf as my HTML5 template engine. I have been following  the OpenCJ.Js tutorial [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/df/d6c/tutorial_js_face_detection_camera.html). I am suppose to get two output, one that will display the VideoInput and the other one the canvas that will display the Canvaoutput where the face tracking will take place.

However, the Video display and its working as expected. However, the Canvas display did not show. When I inspect my code in the chrome browser, I realize that I am getting an Uncaught Reference error which says CV is not defined.

Can somebody assist to tell me if their is anything I am doing wrong in my Code.

Below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/web/thymeleaf/layout" layout:decorate="layout">

<head>
    <script async type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/opencv/opencv.js}"></script>
    <title>Self-Service Portal</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Trying OpenCV Javascript Computer Vision</h2>
    <p id="status">Loading with OpenCV.js...</p>

    <video id="video" autoplay="true" play width="300" height="225"></video> <br/>
    <canvas id="canvasOutput" autoplay="true" width="300" height="225"></canvas>

    <!--div>
    <div class="inputoutput">
    <img id="imageSrc" alt="No Image" />
    <div class="caption">ImageScr<input type="file" id="fileInput" name="file" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="inputoutput">
    <canvas id="canvasOutput" ></canvas>
    <div class="caption">canvasOutput</div>
  </div>
</div-->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                video: true,
                audio: false
            })
            .then(function(stream) {
                video.srcObject = stream;
                video.play();
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log("An error occured While accessing media! " + err);
            });

        let video = document.getElementById('video');
        let src = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4);
        let dst = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4);
        let gray = new cv.Mat();
        let cap = new cv.VideoCapture(video);
        let faces = new cv.RectVector();
        let classifier = new cv.CascadeClassifier();

        //load pre-trained classifiers
        classifier.load('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml');

        const FPS = 30;

        function processVideo() {
            try {
                if (!streaming) {
                    // clean and stop.
                    src.delete();
                    dst.delete();
                    gray.delete();
                    faces.delete();
                    classifier.delete();
                    return;
                }
                let begin = Date.now();
                // start processing.
                cap.read(src);
                src.copyTo(dst);
                cv.cvtColor(dst, gray, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 0);
                // detect faces.
                classifier.detectMultiScale(gray, faces, 1.1, 3, 0);
                // draw faces.
                for (let i = 0; i < faces.size(); ++i) {
                    let face = faces.get(i);
                    let point1 = new cv.Point(face.x, face.y);
                    let point2 = new cv.Point(face.x + face.width, face.y + face.height);
                    cv.rectangle(dst, point1, point2, [255, 0, 0, 255]);
                }
                cv.imshow('canvasOutput', dst);
                // schedule the next one.
                let delay = 1000 / FPS - (Date.now() - begin);
                setTimeout(processVideo, delay);
            }
            catch (err) {
                utils.printError(err);
            }
        };

        //schedule the first one.
        setTimeout(processVideo, 0);
    </script>
    <!--script async src="/opencv/opencv.js" onload="onOpenCvReady;" type="text/javascript"></script-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I normally format code for people when they post something unpleasant to look at, but not this.  Please format that code properly.

Comment: Thank you. comment noted. Nobody is about a mistake. I really appreciate and take kindly the criticisms

Answer (score 1):

The cv is not defined error can be fixed by assigning cv to the window cv object like, `let cv = window.cv`

Turning off async would not be ideal because the OpenCV JS library is large and it would affect the time to initial load. Maybe assign a state variable that changes when it finishes loading and run a check on this variable and update the UI accordingly

Answer (score 1):

the code you find in the examples on the opencv page usually focuses on the functionality of the library and sometimes they do not have all the necessary functions to work. The examples on the opencv page usually use a utils.js file that contains the additional functions to work and this is not so obvious.

Most likely your problem will be solved with the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56671436/cv-mat-is-not-a-constructor-opencv/63211547#63211547) of this forum.
Additionally I have created a [codesandbox](https://hsotb.csb.app/) that contains all the necessary functions for the video examples to work. Normally they will work for you if you replace the code under the comment

```
/ ** Your example code here * /
```

by your facial recognition code.

Comment: This was so much help bro!

Answer (score 0):

The `async` on

```
<script async type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/opencv/opencv.js}"></script>
```

...means it won't hold up parsing and processing of the following markup while waiting for the file to load; [details](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#attr-script-async). So your inline script later in the file can run **before** that file is loaded and its JavaScript is run.

Remove `async` and move that `script` tag to the bottom of the document, just *before* your inline script that uses what it defines.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at this shortly and report back here if it works or not