# cv.Mat is not a constructor opencv

Tags: javascript, opencv

I am getting this bug  TypeError: cv.Mat is not a constructor

I tried doing almost everything can't find any solution on internet

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Hello OpenCV.js</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Hello OpenCV.js</h2>
<p id="status">OpenCV.js is loading...</p>
<div>
<img src="dd.jpg" style="display:none;" id ="img">
<canvas id = "videoInput" height="500" width="500"></canvas>
<canvas id = "canvasOutput" height="500" width="500"></canvas>

<script async type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
<script async src="opencv.js" onload="onOpenCvReady();" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'OpenCV.js is ready.';
  let video = document.getElementById('videoInput');
  let src = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4);
  let dst = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4);
  let gray = new cv.Mat();
  let cap = new cv.VideoCapture(video);
  let faces = new cv.RectVector();
  let classifier = new cv.CascadeClassifier();

  // load pre-trained classifiers
  classifier.load('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml');

  const FPS = 30;
  function processVideo() {
      try {
          if (!streaming) {
              // clean and stop.
              src.delete();
              dst.delete();
              gray.delete();
              faces.delete();
              classifier.delete();
              return;
          }
          let begin = Date.now();
          // start processing.
          cap.read(src);
          src.copyTo(dst);
          cv.cvtColor(dst, gray, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 0);
          // detect faces.
          classifier.detectMultiScale(gray, faces, 1.1, 3, 0);
          // draw faces.
          for (let i = 0; i < faces.size(); ++i) {
              let face = faces.get(i);
              let point1 = new cv.Point(face.x, face.y);
              let point2 = new cv.Point(face.x + face.width, face.y + face.height);
              cv.rectangle(dst, point1, point2, [255, 0, 0, 255]);
          }
          cv.imshow('canvasOutput', dst);
          // schedule the next one.
          let delay = 1000/FPS - (Date.now() - begin);
          setTimeout(processVideo, delay);
      } catch (err) {
          utils.printError(err);
      }
  };

  // schedule the first one.
  setTimeout(processVideo, 0);
}
```

I am also importing opencv.js as i have a downloaded version of it. Guess theres some initialization problem , please help me solve it ...

Comment: It looks like you have a race condition between loading your `index.js` file and the `opencv.js` file. Does it work if you remove the `async` script attributes and load `opencv.js` before `index.js`?

Comment: No it gives the same error @rob3c

Comment: It's clear that `cv.Mat` isn't available when you're calling it (or else it shouldn't be used with `new`, but I doubt that). You have `onload="onOpenCvReady();"` declared, but you're not using it to wait until `opencv.js` is loaded. Try putting your `index.js` code in a function called `onOpenCvReady()` so it'll be called after the `opencv.js` script loads.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

opencv.js loads and fires the onload event before it's really initialized. To wait until opencv.js is really ready, opencv.js provides a on hook "onRuntimeInitialized".  Use it something like this:

```js
function openCvReady() {
  cv['onRuntimeInitialized']=()=>{
    // do all your work here
  };
}
```

Comment: Info: this is only true for WASM builds. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63211547/5267751) for information on how to handle both cases.

Answer (score 7):

1. Make sure that the script is really loaded. If the error is "cv is not defined", then either remove the `async` in the script tag or add this (or just an `onload` attribute in the `<script>` tag)

   ```
    script.addEventListener('load', () => {
   ```
2. In the WASM build (and only the WASM build), cv will not be immediately available because WASM is compiled in runtime. Assign the start function to `cv.onRuntimeInitialized`.

   Note that the WASM version should be faster; however, it incurs some start overhead (a few CPU seconds). The non-WASM doesn't call `onRuntimeInitialized` at all.

   To check both cases, it's possible to do this

   ```
   if (cv.getBuildInformation)
   {
       console.log(cv.getBuildInformation());
       onloadCallback();
   }
   else
   {
       // WASM
       cv['onRuntimeInitialized']=()=>{
           console.log(cv.getBuildInformation());
           onloadCallback();
       }
   }
   ```

Source:

- https://answers.opencv.org/question/207288/how-can-i-compile-opencvjs-so-that-it-does-not-require-defining-the-onruntimeinitialized-field/
- https://docs.opencv.org/master/utils.js

Comment: I used `if (cv.getBuildInformation)` to check cv is loaded or not.  `cv['onRuntimeInitialized']` doesn't work when I refreshed page and it makes sense, this callback is called on runtime initialization for once.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57849449/how-to-solve-typeerror-cv-mat-is-not-a-constructor-opencv-js/57849450#57849450). My solution was different to the one suggested. It has more flexibility since your operations will not be limited to a certain method called in the beginning of your code.

**Step 1:** and it's a very important one, since it actually affected my code: 
Make sure there are no unrelated errors on loading the page. It disrupted the loading of opencv.js

**Step 2:** make sure you load the script synchronously.

```html
<script src="<%= BASE_URL %>static/opencv.js" id="opencvjs"></script>
```

That was it for me. It worked perfectly from that point.