# how to solve TypeError: cv.Mat is not a constructor opencv.js?

Tags: javascript, html, opencv, vue.js

I have a problem using opencv.js when I want to detect aruco markers from my camera. Every time I try to use the method

```
let image = new cv.imread('img');
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: cv.Mat is not a constructor
    at Object.matFromImageData (VM52998 opencv.js:55)
```

I tried to use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56671436/cv-mat-is-not-a-constructor-opencv) to try and solve my issue. The solution from the question was to use async load, call `onOpenCvReady()` when the script is loaded, which will set a handler for `onRuntimeInitialized` event of cv. The handler should perform the necessary operations.

```html
<script>
        function onOpenCvReady() {
            cv['onRuntimeInitialized']=()=>{
                alert('OpenCV.js is ready.');
                // do all operations 
</script>
<script async src="<%= BASE_URL %>static/opencv.js" onload="onOpenCvReady();"></script>
```

However, when I tried to use the solution from the question I encoutered a problem:
the function `onOpenCvReady()` wasn't called at all.

In addition, I waited for more than 15 minutes (just to be sure) and then tried to use the line `javascript let image = new cv.imread('img');` directly in console. Every move I made, and every step I took results in the same issue.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After going back to square 1, I had retried the most basic of solutions:
I just added this to my HTML page, instead of everything written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56671436/cv-mat-is-not-a-constructor-opencv).

```html
<script src="<%= BASE_URL %>static/opencv.js" id="opencvjs"></script>
```

This didn't directly worked, but after debugging some other areas of my code, I made sure that my page doesn't contain other errors (which are not related to this issue at all). For some reason I've yet to investigate and fully understand, having other errors while loading the opencv.js script has interrupted the loading process. Although it sounds unrelated, this had a huge effect on opencv commands.

The end result was magnificent:

```
let image = new cv.imread('img');
console.log(image);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Mat {$$: {…}}
```