# Open CV JS to access webcam and show output

Tags: javascript, opencv

I am super new to JAVA Script. I started to learn Open CV JS. My goal is to get input from the web camera and apply some filter and show output in canvas. But seems like I am making some mistake in importing CV. I am always getting **TypeError: cv.Mat is not a constructor**. After some googling I figured out that open cv is not loading completely so I gave this "onload" function. But the error persists.

Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Learning</title>
</head>

<body>
    <video id="input_video" height="480" width="640"></video>
    <canvas id="output_video" height="480" width="640"></canvas>
    
    <script>
        async function playVideo() {
            let video = document.getElementById('input_video'); //add a video tag with id videoElement
            let frame = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4)
            video.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false });
            video.play();
            cv.imshow('output_video', frame)
        };
    </script>

    <!-- CALLING OPEN CV JAVASCRIPT -->
    <script async src="https://docs.opencv.org/master/opencv.js" id="opencvjs" onload="playVideo()"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cv.Mat is not a constructor opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56671436/cv-mat-is-not-a-constructor-opencv)

Comment: Thanks, @ShriHariL, I tried that and when I do it removes the Type error however it's not showing the video from the web camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned refer the [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63211547/11566161) and in your `playVideo()` add some checks before you play the video.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#examples

```
async function playVideo() {
    let video = document.getElementById('input_video'); //add a video tag with id videoElement
    let frame = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4)

    const mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false });
    if ("srcObject" in video) {
        video.srcObject = mediaStream;
    } else {
        // Avoid using this in new browsers, as it is going away.
        video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaStream);
    }
    video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
      video.play();
    };
    cv.imshow('output_video', frame);
};

async function onCVLoad() {
    if (cv.getBuildInformation) {
        console.log(cv.getBuildInformation());
        playVideo();
    }
    else {
        // WASM
        if (cv instanceof Promise) {
            cv = await cv;
            console.log(cv.getBuildInformation());
            playVideo();
        } else {
            cv['onRuntimeInitialized'] = () => {
                console.log(cv.getBuildInformation());
                playVideo();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

```
subprocess.Popen([FILE], shell=True)
```

There's two things to correct here.

A .jpg image typically won't be executable, so you need something like

```
cmd = "imgviewer.exe"
```

and Popen / run is looking for a `[cmd, FILE]` list *or* for a shell command string like `f"{cmd} {file}"` with that True flag, but not both.
(And I won't even touch the human confusion that `file` vs `FILE` is just asking for.)

So rephrase as:

```
child = subprocess.run([cmd, FILE])
sleep(6)
os.kill(child.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

There should be no need for psutils.

Comment: Thank you very much :). I will learn this.